# Problema na view MVC (erro CS0411)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

cadastro da forma de pagamento na view (cshtml)

```
@model Clinica.Models.DtoPagamento

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "cadPag";
}

<h2>cadPag</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("cadPag"))
{
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.SetNm_pagamento);
}

atributos do DtoPagamento

    public class DtoPagamento
    {
        private int cd_pagamento;
        private string nm_pagamento;

        public int GetCd_pagamento() { return cd_pagamento; }
        public string GetNm_pagamento() { return nm_pagamento; }

        public void SetCd_pagamento(int cd_pagamento) { this.cd_pagamento = cd_pagamento; }
        public void SetNm_pagamento(string nm_pagamento) { this.nm_pagamento = nm_pagamento; }
    }
```

foi informado o erro

```
CS0411: The type arguments for method
'EditorExtensions.EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel>,
Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problema resolvido, segue a explicação no stackoverflow em ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996901/how-exactly-are-the-get-and-set-methods-used-and-implemented-in-c-sharp

eu estava tentando fazer algo que o `c#` já quando eu uso `{get; set;}`. então eu poderia fazer tanto assim:

```
public string nm_pagamento { get; set; }
```

como assim:

```
private string nm_pagamento;
public string Nm_pagamento
{
 get { return nm_pagamento; }
 set { nm_pagamento = value; }
}
```

ambos dariam a mesma coisa, mas com menos linhas.

Answer (score 0):

`SetNm_pagamento` é um método e não um tipo e você não pode utilizar o `EditorFor()` para um método, apenas para uma propriedade da sua model

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("cadPag"))
{
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.nm_pagamento);
}
```

Comment: boa tarde, obrigado pela resposta, Leandro. mas o campo "nm_pagamento" é privado. eu estava vendo se eu conseguia aplicar o encapsulamento no mvc, mas acabou dando esse erro. obrigado.

Comment: Sim, faltou esse detalhe, só vai funcionar com propriedades públicas